# Как придать переменной противоположное значение?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
a = -2.5427
```

должно быть

```
a = 2.5427
```

Answer (score 8):

Вы хотите обратить знак на противоположный.
Везде это делается так:

```
a = -a
```

Answer (score 1):

```
a *= -1                          # То же самое как а = a * -1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> a = -2.5427
>>> a
-2.5427
>>> a = abs(a)
>>> a
2.5427
```

https://pythonz.net/references/named/abs/

Answer (score 0):

Очевидно, что это делается сменой знака:
Можно либо присвоить числу противоположный знак `a=-a` , `a=a*(-1)`, либо взять это число **по абсолютному значению**. Имейте ввиду, что числа в  языке питон являются **неизменяемыми**, и поэтому лучше , сменяя знак, присвоить число другой переменной- `b=-a` или`b=abs(a)` или `b=a*(-1)`

Comment: Числа неизменяемые, а значения в переменных (привязываемые к переменным) изменяемые. Поэтому не обязательно присваивать значение именно другой переменной, можно и той же самой.